# Using TaskEither with fetch API in fp-ts

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I want to wrap Fetch API in fp-ts in some manner:

1. create request
2. check status
3. if status is ok - return json

```js
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
import { flow } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/pipeable';

const safeGet = (url: string): TE.TaskEither<Error, Response> => TE.tryCatch(
  () => fetch(url),
  (reason) => new Error(String(reason))
);

const processResponce = flow(
  (x: Response): E.Either<Error, Response> => {
    return x.status === 200
      ? E.right(x)
      : E.left(Error(x.statusText))
  },
  TE.fromEither
);

export const httpGet = (url: string): TE.TaskEither<Error, Response> => pipe(
  safeGet(url),
  TE.chain(processResponce)
);
```

With this example after running httpGet I get an Response and need to eval .json() method manually. So how can I avoid this behavior and get json inside pipe?

Comment: How are you calling `httpGet`? What response are you seeing?

Comment: const getActivities = httpGet('https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Activities/1');
getActivities().then(x => console.log(x));


And I got:


{
  _tag: 'Right',
  right: Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [Gunzip], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Activities/1',
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Headers],
      counter: 0
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 4):

Just chain this into your flow?

```
const safeJson = <T = unknown>(resp: Response): TE.TaskEither<Error, T> => TE.tryCatch(
  () => resp.json(),
  (reason) => new Error(String(reason))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to fp-ts, but I wonder if you could leverage the library's json module. There's a `parse` and `stringify` function in there that returns an `Either`. My 2¢:

https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Json.ts.html#parse